# Scroll speed for scroll-behavior: smooth

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Is there a way to control the speed of the autoScroll javaScript functions such as scrollTo and ScrollTop?
If there are any solutions in angular thats appreciated as well.

I know there is behavior: smooth but that doesnt change how fast it scrolls
My useCase is for autoScrolling small distances which don't look like a "proper scroll".

Comment: do you need to scroll such short distances anyhow? What does the user gain from this experience?

Comment: That's not really the point @cloned, this is still a legitimate question

Comment: I never said that this isn't a valid question. Just some food for thought. If I thought this want a legitimate question I would have voted to close it @AaronMeese

Comment: @cloned fair enough, good point!

Comment: @cloned it’s for a messaging app. I want that if I have div with messages, to add one below the view and scroll down so that the question comes up. Now it just appears which is not too bad but I just stumbled over this and there has to be a way to do that somehow.